# Laplace’s equation in the Polar Coordinate System

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Laplace’s equation in the Polar Coordinate System:

$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial{x^2}}+\frac{\partial}{\partial{y^2}}=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial{r^2}}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial{r}}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial{\theta^2}}=\nabla^2$$

$$\nabla^2u=0 \Rightarrow u_{rr}+\frac{1}{r}u_r+u_{\theta \theta}=0$$

We suppose that we have a circular disc, that means 
$$0 \leq r <a$$
$$0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi$$

Boundary conditions: $u(r=a, \theta)=h(\theta), 0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi$

**The boundary condition has to be continuous everywhere, so it should be $h(0)=h(2 \pi)$.**

$u(r, \theta)=R(r)\Theta(\theta)$

Replacing this at the equation, we get the following problems:

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
\Theta''+\lambda \Theta=0\\ 
\Theta(0)=\Theta(2\pi)
\end{matrix}\right.$$

$$r^2R''+rR'-\lambda R=0, 0 \leq r <a, (*)$$

**Since the function $\Theta$ is periodic with period $2 \pi$ we have $k=n$**
$$\Theta=A \cos{(k \theta)}+B \sin{(k \theta)}, k=n, n=0,1,2,\dots$$

Therefore $$\Theta_n=A_n \cos{(n \theta)} + B_n \sin{(n \theta)}, 0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi$$
$$\lambda_n =n^2$$
$$(*) \Rightarrow r^2R''+rR'-n^2R=0$$
$$$$
Could you explain if the following two sentences?

**1.** The boundary condition has to be continuous everywhere, so it should be $h(0)=h(2 \pi)$.

**2.** Since the function $\Theta$ is periodic with period $2 \pi$ we have $k=n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both come from the same fact, that angle $2\pi$ radians and angle $0$ are the same.

EDIT:

[image]

The black dot is $r=a, \theta = 0$ and also $r = a, \theta = 2 \pi$.
In order for the boundary condition to be continuous, it has to have the
same limiting value as you approach a point from any direction.  As
you approach the black dot along the circle from above, $\theta \to 0$.
As you approach the black dot along the circle from below, $\theta \to 
2 \pi$.

Comment: I got stuck... Why is the boundary condition continuous when $h(0)=h(2π)$??

Comment: Because both give you the value of $u$ at the same point, $(a,0)$ in cartesian (rectangular) coordinates.

Comment: And what does this mean? I haven't understood it..

Comment: I got it!!! Thanks a lot!!! :-)

Comment: I got stuck right now...Why should the function $\Theta$ have a periodic solution?